# optgroup with options to ul with li

Tags: jquery, select, html-lists, dropdown

I'm making a custom select dropdown. I'm trying to convert the options to li elements which works so far. For the conversion I simply use $(selector).each(..). But I want, if they exist inside the select element, convert the opgroups to ul elements and place their options inside of them as li elements.

**So to brake it down**
**If I have:** 
<select>
 <option>
 <option> 
<option>
</select>
**or**
<select>
<optgroup>
 <option>
<option>
<option> 
</optgroup>
</select>

**Should become:**
<li>
 <li> 
<li>
**or**
<ul>
 <li>
<li>
<li> 
</ul>

How can I achieve this in jQuery?
Like I want to have the optgroups as ul only if they are in the select. And the options in the right ul based on their optgroup. My problem right now is that I get all the options in every optgroup (so the same options in every optgroup which is NOT what I want).

*The optgroup should become the ul to which the appropriate options must be appended as li elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the current element which is refer inside each loop is `OPTGROUP` using
`prop("tagName")` if yes use `each loop` to loop through `option` tags inside that and append generated html .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var html = "";
$("select > * ").each(function() {
  //check tag name
  if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "OPTGROUP") {
    html += "<ul>" //create ul append it
    //loop throuh options
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
      html += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>" //append li
    })
    html += "</ul>" //close ul tag
  } else {
    html += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>" //if option is there
  }
})
$("#result").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option> S </option>
  <optgroup label="First">
    <option> A </option>
    <option> B </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Second">
    <option> E </option>
    <option> F </option>
  </optgroup>
  <option> R </option>

</select>


<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: It worked great, however if i were to add multiple selects how can I make sure the right options are appended to the right select? Right now all the same options are appended to all the select elements.

Comment: Hi , can you another question for this ..let me know then :) will help you there

Comment: Well it's related to this question so I'm afraid if I open a new question it will be removed.

Comment: i see so can you make jsfiddle with your current issue?

Comment: Sure can! Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/32eu617m/39/

Comment: so here you need to make selectbox from ul li ? am i right ? i am little bit confuse here .

Comment: No wait let me ajust the fiddle for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226743/discussion-between-swati-and-leonator).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery `each` method you could do something like this:

```
  <select>
    <option value="">Test 1</option>
    <option value="">Test 2</option>
    <option value="">Test 3</option>
  </select>

  <ul></ul>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      

      $('select option').each(function() {

        var li = '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
        $('ul').append(li);

      });


    })

  </script>
```

Comment: No, ofcourse I already done that and it works, but what I'm looking for is a way to make it work with optgroups aswell. So if I add an optgroup the optgroup will function as the ul element. But thanks for your quick answer though!

Comment: Then you can check for the element nodename on the loop. 
if ($(this)[0].nodeName == 'OPTGROUP') { // do something }

Comment: But in that case you would need to change the selector to $('select *').each(